# Is there a way to get social share counts on AMP pages?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, amp-html

I'm building out AMP pages and I'm looking to show how many times this URL has been shared on the various social sites like Facebook, Twitter and Pinterest.

For example, lets say our AMP url is https://www.example.com/test-post/ and it has been shared on Facebook 20 times. I want to pull that info and display it on the page.

Normally this is easily done with an ajax request, but we cannot use any custom javascript on the AMP pages. Does anybody have a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

None that I know of. None mentioned in [AMP-social-share](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-social-share).